# Plot cox function/curve for a given set of values (case cohort data, cch)

Tags: r

I just created a weigthed cox regression using the cch-function from the survival package:

```
data("nwtco")  
subcoh <- nwtco$in.subcohort
selccoh <- with(nwtco, rel==1|subcoh==1)
ccoh.data <- nwtco[selccoh,]
ccoh.data$subcohort <- subcoh[selccoh]
ccoh.data$age <- ccoh.data$age/12 

   seqno instit histol stage study rel edrel      age in.subcohort subcohort
4      4      2      1     4     3   0  6200 2.333333         TRUE      TRUE
7      7      1      1     4     3   1   324 3.750000        FALSE     FALSE
11    11      1      2     2     3   0  5570 2.000000         TRUE      TRUE
14    14      1      1     2     3   0  5942 1.583333         TRUE      TRUE
17    17      1      1     2     3   1   960 7.166667        FALSE     FALSE
22    22      1      1     2     3   1    93 2.666667        FALSE     FALSE

cchmodel <- cch(Surv(edrel, rel) ~ stage + histol + age, 
                data =ccoh.data,
                subcoh = ~subcohort, 
                id=~seqno, 
                cohort.size=4028, 
                method="LinYing")
```

I would then like to display the result by creating a graph showing the curves for two different set of values. That is, creating a graph showing the curves for:

1. stage = 1,   age = mean age,   histol = 1
2. stage = 4,   age = mean age,   histol = 1

It may be a bit tricky since I am using the cch-funtion. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: The problem that I see is two-fold:  no description of the cohort and sampling (in this case) and more generally there would be no way to construct a proper risk set to serve as a denominator. Survival calculations imply that you know the number of survivors in the population at any given event time, but the sampling design of a case within cohort study doesn't  supply that information. It only really gives you information about the distribution of risk factors rather than the total number of survivors with those risk factors.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand? The sampling done in the case cohort design is accounted for by weighting the cox regression - and from my understanding, it should be possible to estimate curves based on the regression results?

Comment: I thought this was a case-control design, but apparently Therneau thinks you can get sufficient design info from it to run cch properly. I suspect that the survival curve will need to be constructed with the full dataset rather than the sampled subcohort.